# Prove that the set $S$ of rational points in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that the set $S$  of rational points in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ is denumerable.

[A point $p = (x,y) \in  \mathbb R^2$ is rational if $x$ and $y$ are rational.]